# Create a converter for selectOneMenu at runtime

Tags: java, jsf

So I need to create a screen that is dynamic and provides information about objects wich have an unknown number of parameters, of various types (could be texte, could be date, and, thing that causes problem, could be an item to select from a SelectOneMenu, whose binding (like "#{myBean.list}" and converter (like "#{somethingConverter}) are fields of the parameter.

So, to create the SelectOneMenu, I've got something like this:

```
    SelectOneMenu menu = new SelectOneMenu();
    UISelectItems items = new UISelectItems();

    ValueExpression expr = getValueExpression(param.binding); //param.binding is a String containing the expression
    items.setValueExpression("value", expr);

    menu.getChildren().add(items);
    panel.getChildren().add(menu);
}


private ValueExpression getValueExpression(String expression) {
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext expressionContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    return expressionFactory.createValueExpression(expressionContext, expression, Object.class);
}
```

But I have to set a Converter to the menu to, and I can't use the same method because it's impossible to instantiate a Converter, so I can't juste set it an expression.

I tried using reflection, and it almost works, but in my Converters , some managers are created using

```
    @Inject
    private SomeManager mManager;
```

And if I create a converter using reflection, those managers aren't created, and I end up getting a NullPointerException when I use them.

So is there a way I can dynamically create a converter using the expression I would put after "converter=" in my XHtml page ?
Or, using reflection, to force my converter classes to do the "inject" instantiation ?

Thank for your help !

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the part *"because it's impossible to instantiate a Converter"* which is basically your root problem. This is namely not impossible (even more, JSF itself is doing that successfully "under the covers" when you use `<f:converter>` and so on). Please elaborate the concrete problem in more detail. How exactly does that step fail for you?

Comment: Well converter is an interface so I can't just do:

        Converter lConverter= new Converter();
        lConverter.setValueExpression("value",expr);

I don't know the compoenent f:converter, what is its class name ? Can't find it on Eclipse, but it might be a solution

Comment: usually I just put converter="#{someClassConverter}" in the selectOneMenu

Comment: Are you new to Java or so? You usually just do `Converter converter = new SomeClassConverter()`. It's exactly the same way as how `List list = new ArrayList()` works. This concrete problem is further completely unrelated to JSF.

Comment: Problem being, I don't know in advance what "SomeClassConverter" I should use. It's in a String. And I can't juste get it by reflection for the reasons I said before.

Comment: Oh right, I overlooked that part in the question. If your converters are managed beans instead of faces converters, rather use `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()` instead of `Application#createConverter()` or `new SomeConverter()` to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I tried using reflection, and it almost works, but in my Converters , some managers are created using*
>
> ```
> @Inject
> private SomeManager mManager;
> ```
>
> *And if I create a converter using reflection, those managers aren't created, and I end up getting a NullPointerException when I use them.*

In other words, your converters are managed beans (e.g. `@Named` or `@ManagedBean`), not faces converters (e.g. `@FacesConverter` or `<converter>`)? In that case, you'd need to create them by programmatically evaluating the EL expression referencing it like so

```
Converter converter = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{someConverter}", Converter.class);
```